# Create a list of list based on requirement in R

Tags: r, loops

Hi I want to create a list that has a list of all same value excluding a first value

```
  
area = [1200,1300,1200,1300,1200,2000]
price = [12000,24000,14000,22000,13000,30000]

for (i in 1:length(area)){
  for(x in 1:length(area)){
    if(area[i]==area[x]&i!=x)
      temp = area[x]
      print(temp)
  }
}

**Desired output**

output 
complist = 
[14000,13000] (exclude 12000)-they have same value in area 1200,
[22000] (exclude 24000)-they have same value in area 1300
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work. Basically it's probably easiest to create a dataframe (tibble), filter to the data points needed, then finally convert back to list (if that's what's truly needed).

```
    library(dplyr)
    aa <- tibble(area = c(1200,1300,1200,1300,1200,2000),
          price = c(12000,24000,14000,22000,13000,30000))
    aa2 <- aa %>% group_by(area) %>% mutate(occ=row_number()) %>% filter(occ!=1) %>% arrange(area)
    split(aa2$price,aa2$area)
```

EDIT:
For including areas with only one data point, this should work:

```
library(dplyr)
aa <- tibble(area = c(1200,1300,1200,1300,1200,2000),price = c(12000,24000,14000,22000,13000,30000))
aa2 <- aa %>% group_by(area) %>% mutate(occ=row_number()) %>% filter(occ!=1) %>% arrange(area)
aa3 <- aa %>% semi_join(aa %>% group_by(area) %>% tally() %>% filter(n==1))
aa4 <- bind_rows(aa2,aa3)
split(aa4$price,aa4$area)
```

Comment: then if 2000 (they dont have other same value, it doesnt appear

Comment: I've edited to include that, but please note that your desired output didn't include the [2000] case.